# d3.js canvas zoom and pan with bounds

Tags: d3.js

I've been pretty easily able to set up zooming and panning a map in canvas following Mike Bostock's block here: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/c1c0426d50ca8a9f4c97

However, is there a way to prevent the user from panning off screen? In that block, you can zoom out and drag the map off the screen. **Is there a way to make sure the user always sees only the map?**

Comment: There are a lot of resources containing the type of behavior you're looking for. Try [this](http://bl.ocks.org/tommct/5671250) or [this](http://techslides.com/demos/d3/d3-worldmap-boilerplate.html).

Comment: @jsbob both of those examples are projected SVG paths. Zooming/panning in canvas with pre-projected geography is a bit different unfortunately.